# Two way finite state Automaton NP Compleness definition clarification?

Tags: automata

INSTANCE: A two-way nondeterministic finite state automaton A over single Alphabet I.
QUESTION: Is there an string x (over I) such that A accepts x ?

Since a 2-way NFA with N states, there’s an equivalent nfa with n^(n+1) states. So that’s we get the exponential time from.

I am clear about that, but if I understand correctly the size of the string accepted by the 2Way NFA would still be (in the worst case) polynomial to number of states in the 2Way NFA. Cause if the smallest string accepted was exponential in size, the verification will also take exponential time and thus the problem by definition would not be NP Complete ? Or is there a mistake in this reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

For a problem to be in NP, there needs to be a polynomial time verifier for it. This polynomial time verifier need not be the "obvious" one. Ruling out one specific verifier doesn't prove that the problem is not in NP.

For a problem to be NP-complete, it needs to satisfy two properties: (i) it needs to be in NP, and (ii) it need to be NP-hard. You can look these concepts up in many sources. In particular, the fact that there is some natural exponential time algorithm for a problem *doesn't* imply that it is NP-complete, though it is true that every problem in NP has an exponential time algorithm.

Unfortunately I am not versed well enough in two-way automata to answer your specific question, but my comments above imply that the answer doesn't necessarily have a direct bearing on whether the emptiness problem for 2NFAs is NP-complete or not (or even in NP or not).

Comment: Much thanks. The problem IS NP-Complete. The Reference (G&J): [AL2] TWO-WAY FINITE STATE AUTOMATON NON-EMPTINESS (*) - "PSPACE-complete, even if |I|=2 and A is deterministic. If |l| = l 
the general problem is NP-complete "

So if they state its NP-Complete the string (case |l| = 1), if at all there is a string that is accepted by a given 2 Way NFA (i.e. the Automaton is non-empty), by definition of NP, it would always mean that the length of string would be polynomial in size w.r.t. the Size of Automaton (i.e. the number of states in it) in the 'worst case' ?

Comment: No. It just means that there is some way to verify (given a witness) in polynomial time that the language accepted by a 2NFA over a unary alphabet is non-empty. It doesn't mean that a particular algorithm (given a string as witness, verify that the 2NFA accepts it) works in polynomial time. It just means that *some* algorithm does.

Comment: understood. The paper itself (mentioned in G&J [AL2]) is a paid one and i don't have access to it. Thus, couldn't see the verifier part and how they verify.

Comment: Prof. I am still struggling with this. If the witness is the string (exponential in length) then even the reading of it will take exponential time. So that is out of question. But, I don't see another way to represent a unary string such that the witness (exactly corresponding to it) is polynomial length and is verifiable?

Comment: Sometimes the fact that a problem is in NP is not trivial. I suggest taking a look at the paper.

Comment: In fact, encoding an exponentially long unary word only takes polynomial space (since we can encode $1^N$ by encoding $N$ instead, which takes only $O(\log N)$ bits), and this shows that the problem is indeed in NP for a unary alphabet.

Comment: I agree with the encoding part Prof. But, after encoding we need to verify the solution (the definition of NP). and since the machine is in unary we will have to resort to creating an equivalent machine from unary to binary alphabet (in polynomial time). Otherwise its unclear to me how this approach would satisfy the definition of NP. (sadly this is a paid paper and I have no access)

Comment: You probably have to do something smart which uses the fact that the alphabet is unary to enable the verification.

Comment: I agree with that part but have no clue how :) Moreover, even to convert the string we would have to read it. And reading an exponential string itself will take exponential time!